# How to keep navbar elements from overlapping?

Tags: php, html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I am using php to include a navigation bar on a website. I want the words in the navigation bar to not overlap when the browser is resized. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a  class='active' data-scroll-nav='0'>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-scroll-nav='1'>Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-scroll-nav='2'>LP</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-scroll-nav='3'>Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.nav-container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;

}
nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto; 
}
nav ul {
      padding: 0px; 
    }
nav li {
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block; 
}

    nav li a {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white; 
        font-family: Market;
    }
   nav li a.active {
       color: black; 
       text-decoration: none;
       font-size: 200%;
   }
   nav li a.hover{
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #c8c8a9;
   }
```

the html is in a separate file and included in the main file inside a bootstrap container like this:

```
<div class="container">
 <?php
include("header.php"); 
 ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? The answer is in bootstrap docs (Since you're using it): http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Comment: where is your effort?

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap for the navigation. And I have tried using media queries min-width 320px but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this :

- First make your items never break in lines :

  ```
  .nav-container nav ul {
      white-space:nowrap;
  }
  ```
- Two set a `min-width` :

  ```
  .nav-container nav ul li {
      min-width:55px;
  }
  ```

**Edit**

After a few commentaries also need to remove the fixed `width` from `nav ul li`

Comment: I just tried that and it still overlaps when it gets to 320px.

Comment: Then increase the min-width:70px

Comment: That works only when the font-size for the active list item is not 200%, is there a way for the words to clear each other when they get bigger? Like when that list item is active meaning that's the current page your on the font size of that item doubles.

Comment: ?only when the font-size for the active list item is not 200% ? i don't understand what you really need with this elements your menu never gets overlaped items

Comment: So when your on a particular page I changed the code so that the font gets bigger. However when it gets bigger it overlaps the next word when the screen size is under 320px.